# Command Prompt freezes when creating a venv

Tags: python, django, windows

I am starting a new django project and when I try to add a venv to the project folder my command prompt freezes at the last line of the following code:

```
C:\Users\ab\workspace\rc>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\ab\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32'
New python executable in C:\Users\ab\workspace\rc\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

Same thing when I try to install it using the command prompt in my PyCharm project.

When I Control-C I see the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\ab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
        symlink=options.symlink)
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
        download=download,
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
        call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 786, in call_subprocess
        logger.info(line)
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 198, in info
        self.log(self.INFO, msg, *args, **kw)
      File "c:\users\ab\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 220, in log
        if self.level_matches(level, consumer_level):
    KeyboardInterrupt
```

When I try vitrualenv venv -v I get:

```
Creating C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Lib
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\os.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: posix
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\posixpath.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: nt
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\ntpath.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\genericpath.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\fnmatch.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\locale.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\encodings
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\codecs.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\stat.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: UserDict
  Cannot import bootstrap module: readline
  Cannot import bootstrap module: copy_reg
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\types.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\re.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: sre
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\sre_parse.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\sre_constants.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\sre_compile.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: zlib
  Cannot import bootstrap module: _abcoll
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\warnings.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\linecache.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\abc.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\io.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\_weakrefset.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\copyreg.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\tempfile.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\random.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\__future__.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\collections
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\keyword.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\tarfile.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\shutil.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\struct.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\copy.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\tokenize.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\token.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\functools.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\heapq.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\bisect.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\weakref.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\reprlib.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\base64.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\_dummy_thread.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\hashlib.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\hmac.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\imp.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\importlib
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\rlcompleter.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\operator.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\_collections_abc.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\_bootlocale.py
  Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\enum.py
Creating C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Lib\site-packages
Writing C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\site.py
Writing C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\orig-prefix.txt
Writing C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\no-global-site-packages.txt
Copying to C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Include
Creating C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Scripts
New python executable in C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Changed mode of C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe to 0o777
Also created pythonw.exe
Also created python36.dll
Testing executable with C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import sys;out=sys.stdout;getattr(out, "buffer", out).write(sys.prefix.encode("utf-8"))"
Got sys.prefix result: 'c:\\users\\ab\\desktop\\venv'
Creating C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\distutils
Writing C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\distutils\__init__.py
Writing C:\Users\ab\Desktop\venv\lib\distutils\distutils.cfg
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Collecting setuptools
```

I am on Windows 7. Any idea what is holding it up?

Comment: How long have you waited?  What happens when you issue a keyboard interrupt (i.e. hit `CTRL+C`)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.google.si/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwivw5XLxIHWAhWFbZoKHZKzBB0QtwIIMTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPIxOjvjrkPg&usg=AFQjCNEYLO0ilFWsADg4vBKxKhzJPpN-RQ) and make sure you didn't miss a tiny bit in the process

Comment: @Billy I added what I see after Control-C. As far as how long I wait...30 minutes was the last one.

Comment: Can you please use the -v switch and share the output? `virtualenv venv -v`

Comment: @McMutton I updated the answer with the output

Comment: @McMutton it gets stuck after  Collecting setuptools

Comment: This might be a connectivity issue. If so, and if you wait a bit more you should see a connection time out log. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @McMutton no idea. Will have to call IT. Funny thing is that I was able to create a venv in PyCharm UI by going to Preferences -> Project Interpreter -> Create new venv. But in the command prompt no luck.

Comment: PyCharm may be using your system proxy settings but `virtualenv` looks for environment variables. Can you please check your system proxy by going to: Control Panel --> Network and Internet --> Internet Options --> Connections --> LAN Settings and see if there are any values in the address fields?

Comment: @McMutton nothing there. Just says detect automaticly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153376/discussion-between-mcmutton-and-user3088202).

Comment: @McMutton I gotta run to a meeting. I do appreciate all your help. Thank you again. For now I will just use the UI.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing the correct thing. For creating virtual environment use this command:-

> virtualenv venv

Just you need to wait for few minutes for virtual environment to get created. It will take a minute or two. After the virtual environment gets created you need to activate it using the command:

> . venv/bin/activate

Do not press Ctrl+c while creation. It will terminate the progress.
Visit the following link if required.

http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2011/08/28/python-django-mysql-on-windows-7-part-2-virtual-environments/